# jQuery: Remove error after autocomplete happens in a field

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation, daterangepicker

I'm using the `Daterangepicker` for `Bootstrap` on my only input text field on my page.  When I leave the input text field blank, the error springs up, which is what I want.   However, when I fill in the input text field using the `Daterangepicker`, the error persists.

[image]

I'd like it to be removed.  The error text removes itself when I click the Begin button, but I want the error text to remove itself once text is populated in the input field.

Here's my code:

```
$('#beginBtn').on('click', function() {     
  //Validation of Open Enrollment input
  var autocd = $('#autocd').val();
  if(autocd == "") {
    $('#autocderror').text('Cannot be blank').css({'color': 'red'});
    return false;
  } else if (autocd != "") {
    $('#autocderror').fadeOut(1000);
  }

  var startDate = $("input[name='daterangepicker_start']").val();
  var endDate = $("input[name='daterangepicker_end']").val();

  //console.log(startDate + " thru " + endDate);

  $.post('api/countdownprocess.php', {startDate:startDate, endDate:endDate}, function(data) {
    if(data == 'Successful'){
      $('#oerestext').html(data).css({'color': 'green'}).fadeOut(3000);
      setTimeout(function() {
        location.reload();
      }, 5000);
    } else {
      $('#oerestext').html(data).css({'color': 'red'}).fadeOut(3000);
    }
  });// end of Begin Button
```

The input field is called autocd.  How do I do that?  Is there a way to get autocomplete as a selector?

Answer (score 0):

How about moving this block of code in a function that's triggered by the onchange event on your input?

```
var autocd = $('#autocd').val();
if(autocd == "") {
  $('#autocderror').text('Cannot be blank').css({'color': 'red'});
  return false;
} else if (autocd != "") {
  $('#autocderror').fadeOut(1000);
}
```

Comment: doesn't work.  for some reason, when I wrap the above code in a function, the validation of when the field is blank doesn't fire  But definitely alot closer to what I'm trying to achieve.  Used this as a reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange2